# Latex table with image

Tags: tables

[image]

i was wondering how can i make this in code

```
  \begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c}{} \includegraphics[scale=0.80]{UAGpractica.jpg}  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{} &  \\
                        &                      &  \\
                        &                      &  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
```

Comment: that is presumably a frontpage header, so should just have the `tabular` and not be in `\begin{table}` (which specifies that the content is a float that may be moved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following. The second table uses `tabularx` in order to make the table as wide as the textwidth:

Filling in the correct text is up to you and if you want your image to appear instead of the black square, remove the `demo` option from `graphhicx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|@{}l@{}l@{}|}
\hline
\includegraphics[scale=0.80,valign=c]{UAGpractica.jpg}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{c}
                                                          \textbf{some text}\\
                                                          \hline
                                                          \textbf{some more text}\\
                                                          \textbf{a second line of text}\\
                                                          \hline
                                                          \textbf{third row}\\
                                                          \hline
                                                          four rows of non bold text\\
                                                          four rows of non bold text\\
                                                          four rows of non bold text\\
                                                          four rows of non bold text\\
                                                          \end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{}l@{}c@{}|}
\hline
\includegraphics[scale=0.80,valign=c]{UAGpractica.jpg}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{>{\Centering}X}
                                                          \textbf{some text}\\
                                                          \hline
                                                          \textbf{some more text}\\
                                                          \textbf{a second line of text}\\
                                                          \hline
                                                          \textbf{third row}\\
                                                          \hline
                                                          four rows of non bold text\\
                                                          four rows of non bold text\\
                                                          four rows of non bold text\\
                                                          four rows of non bold text\\
                                                          \end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```